# How can I use RegEx to capture a security token for use within JMeter?

Tags: regex, security, jmeter, token, csrf

I am using JMeter's Regular Expression Extractor to capture a security token from the first HTTP response header to use in future requests.

The HTTP Response is as follows:

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJNVE8iLCJpYXQiOiIxNTEyMDcxNTg1Iiwic3ViIjoiOTEzNjQ0NCIsInV0ayI6InUvenBESVBzOCtUSlZUaW5tYVBaUjBqd2xyd2lJU1lSRVJ1ZnphNUVzS2s9IiwidmVyIjoiMi4wLjguNjIiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTIwNzEyODV9.4y__KpTFSgkdD_dMAuMiClbSfcmnvdtr0IEoVHFB_Fw","sessionTimeoutSeconds":1800,"profileRequirements":null}
```

So I'm trying to capture all the Characters where I wrote RANDOMCHARS

```
{"token":"RANDOMCHARS","sessionTimeoutSeconds":1800,"profileRequirements":null}
```

I plan to use this site to test any suggestions: https://regexr.com/

Any help would be so far beyond appreciated! =)

Comment: `"token"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"`? Your title doesn't make much sense in relation to the question.

Comment: Okay I ran the RegEx within JMeter and the result is: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJNVE8iLCJpYXQiOiIxNTEyMDgwMDQ3Iiwic3ViIjoiOTEzNjQ0NCIsInV0ayI6IjJjb1pjRU0ramQzT3ArNkxTb2pvODhlaVVHdWl5NGM4aVArZC84L2orUjA9IiwidmVyIjoiMi4wLjguNjIiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTIwNzk3NDd9.DY69755kQ8dhODtPiuzuGe6vBS3jgLwXCIsUatjFsZU

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: yes Sir! That worked perfectly!!! Thank you so very much for imparting your knowledge!!!! =) =) =)

Comment: I've posted my answer below. that's the only way to accept an answer haha

Comment: roger that thank ya bro! Thank you for the extra detailed breakdown of the yer Awesome RegEx! =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/z835B3/1)

```
"token"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJNVE8iLCJpYXQiOiIxNTEyMDcxNTg1Iiwic3ViIjoiOTEzNjQ0NCIsInV0ayI6InUvenBESVBzOCtUSlZUaW5tYVBaUjBqd2xyd2lJU1lSRVJ1ZnphNUVzS2s9IiwidmVyIjoiMi4wLjguNjIiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTIwNzEyODV9.4y__KpTFSgkdD_dMAuMiClbSfcmnvdtr0IEoVHFB_Fw","sessionTimeoutSeconds":1800,"profileRequirements":null}
```

#### Output

Output below is capture group 1

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJNVE8iLCJpYXQiOiIxNTEyMDcxNTg1Iiwic3ViIjoiOTEzNjQ0NCIsInV0ayI6InUvenBESVBzOCtUSlZUaW5tYVBaUjBqd2xyd2lJU1lSRVJ1ZnphNUVzS2s9IiwidmVyIjoiMi4wLjguNjIiLCJuYmYiOjE1MTIwNzEyODV9.4y__KpTFSgkdD_dMAuMiClbSfcmnvdtr0IEoVHFB_Fw
```

---

### Explanation

- `"token"` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `:` Match this literally
- `\s*` Match any number of whitespace characters
- `"` Match this literally
- `([^"]*)` Capture any character except `"` into capture group 1
- `"` Match this literallly

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that since JMeter 3.0 you have [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which is designed for fetching values from JSON using [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)  language which is far more quick, easy and stable than regular expressions.

The relevant configuration would be:

- Variable Names: anything meaningful, i.e. `token`
- JSON Path Expressions: `$.token`

That's it, you will be able to refer the extracted value as `${token}` where required.

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Path Extractor]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)